# Laravel - Trying to get property of non-object error on ubuntu server

Tags: php, laravel, object, model

This works on my local server on wamp windows but if I do this on my ubuntu nginx server I get "Trying to get property of non-object", "Call to a member function blocked() on a non-object" and similar errors on both the steam_user and blocked. The data is fetched from mysql db.

In controller:

```
  $steam_user = $order->user()->first();
  $blocked = $steam_user->blocked()->first();
```

In model:

```
    public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Http\Models\SteamUser', 'user_id', 'steam_id');
}

  public function blocked()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Http\Models\Blacklist', 'user_id', 'steam_id');
}
```

Comment: Is there a user in your database? What happens if you dump $steam_user?

Comment: I get an object of the user with "steam_id" => 123 and such

Comment: Try `$order->user` and `$steam_user->blocked` !!